# VB does not acknowledge that my Array entry exists

Tags: arrays, vb.net, image

This is summed up best in an image:

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img713/7263/smct.png]

Where did I go so wrong?

Comment: no, it is best summed up showing the code that results in the error than a picture of an error

Comment: Does the array has multiple "manpower"?

Comment: Have a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, the array does have other occurrences of the manpower string. And that is the code that results in the error, the 14 entry of the array is "manpower". It should at least know that the array contains the string, surely?

Comment: Are you sure that the string is only "manpower" and not "manpower "? Just to check, try to change the first writeline to Console.WriteLine(fileLinesNoNums(14) & ".")

Comment: @Steve Oh, that reminds me. Doing that gives me an output of ".anpower". I just am so confused.

Comment: Oh well, I'll use a for loop to find it instead. Thanks for the time everyone.

Comment: Why are you using Array.Index of instead of fileLinesNoNums.IndexOf??  If I understand correctly, you have an array of strings and you're trying to find the element in the array that matches "manpower", right?  I'd use LINQ to find this.

Comment: The indexOf method is formatted like that, see Satish's link. Also, I think for some reason it's not actually "manpower". I've found a workaround though, so all is good.